# (Angular 5) Error: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder, formarray, angular-formbuilder

I'm initializing my form this way, but when I need to edit it, it does not accept the values

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tinvoiceService.initForm();
}
```

tinvoice.service.ts

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private _fb: FormBuilder, 
  private invoiceService: InvoiceService
) {}

initForm(): void {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    customer: [null, Validators.required],
    totalPrice: 0,
    purchases: this._fb.array([])
  });

  // initialize stream
  const myFormValueChanges$ = this.form.controls['purchases'].valueChanges;
  myFormValueChanges$.subscribe(purchases => this.updatePurchasesAmount(purchases));

}
```

from the HTML I pass the values

tinvoice.component.html

```
<a 
  class="btn btn-outline-info text-info" 
  (click)="tinvoiceService.populateForm(invoice)">
  Edit
</a>
```

tinvoice-list.component.ts

```
populateForm(invoice) {
  this.form.setValue(invoice);  
}
```

by console I have this result

[image]

[View in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-stackoverflow)

any ideas?

Comment: where are you calling `initForm()`?

Comment: another component  ngOnInit() {this.tinvoiceService.initForm();}

Comment: are you sure that initForm() is called before the first time form.setValue() is called? Can you confirm with a console.log()?

Comment: I think there's some serious issue with your `tinvoiceService` . Why exactly are you initializing the form there? Shouldn't it be in your Component?

Answer (score 0):

Form is a UI element, it gets instantiated after view is rendered.

you can try calling this function in `ngAfterViewInit`, the error should be gone. if not just create one fiddle and I will try to fix it for you.

Comment: he's creating a Reactive Form here. So that's not true. It can be done in `ngOnInit` as well in his case.

Comment: @MehuIJoshi add a link with StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

Old Question but will give my view

When a user clicks on the edit button, the console logs works indicates

> Cannot find form control with name: purchases

So we start from here and identify the issue in the line

```typescript
  this.form.setValue(invoice)
```

If we log the value of `invoice` at this point we see

```json
{
    "createdAt": "Mon May 10 2021 15:32:51 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)",
    "customer": {
        "address": "s",
        "lastname": "Perez",
        "name": "Carlos ",
        "phone": "7861236589"
    },
    "purchases": [
        {
            "product": {
                "categoryS": "-MZyCBHUjLrfxzoRdZBM",
                "location": "Store",
                "name": "TV Samsung",
                "price": 50
            },
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "totalPrice": 50,
    "$key": "-M_LgTlysUg07lHdjtuG"
}
```

If we log value of `this.form.value` we aee

```json
{
    "customer": {
        "name": null,
        "lastname": null,
        "address": null,
        "phone": null
    },
    "createdAt": null
}
```

So you are trying to assign the form an incorrect structure of the object.

To check that your code is actually working you can simply change `setValue` to `patchValue`. Below solutions works as `patchValue` will only look for form controls that only exists unlike `setValue`. To use `setValue` on the other hand you will have to ensure that all the properties in your object are represented in the FormGroup, otherwise remove those properties from the object

Below is a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoice-stackoverflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Finvoice-list%2Finvoice-list.component.ts) showing a solution by changing `setValue` to `patchValue`